# Importing Google API fonts not applying in github pages

Tags: html, github, fonts, github-pages

I hosted a theme on [GitHub pages](https://pages.github.com/) , this theme working properly in `localhost` environment, but when I host this its not applying correct font which are importing form Google API

**Difference here**

*Local host version*

[image]

*Githhub Page Version*

[image]

This is my `Index.html` page

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no;">
    <title>Sample Name</title>  

    <!--( b ) CSS Stylesheets -->

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- Library -->

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="library/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="library/popup/popup.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="library/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="library/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css">


        <!-- STYLE Sheets -->

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">

    <!--( c ) Javascript For Browser Support Issues -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="library/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->    

    </head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="library/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="library/easy-pie-charts/jquery.easypiechart.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="library/mixitup/jquery.mixitup.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="library/popup/jquery.popup.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="library/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="library/gMap/jquery.gmap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I debug this using firebug I saw that theme fonts rendering from Google api fonts as following in `style.css` file

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:300,500);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400italic);



#preloader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #1a1b23;
    z-index: 10000;
}

.loader { ...
```

So what can I do here

Comment: Did you check the console?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this might be because the github page is using HTTPS but the font URL is HTTP.

Can you try changing the URL by removing `http:` like in [this example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vXjqGp)?

Comment: thnks that's the mistake

Answer (score 1):

You can use `//` for accessing external URLs

```
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:300,500);
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400italic)
```

Answer (score 1):

Rob's answer fixed my issue perfectly. I just added the following code to my CSS file.

```
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:300,500);

body {
    font-family: Hind;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Make this a comment when you can :)