# Importing Google API fonts as HTTPS still not applying in GitHub pages

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages, google-webfonts

I'm hosting a pre-made theme on GitHub pages and generated with Jekyll. The theme works properly in `localhost`, but the fonts do not display correctly on the actual site hosted on GitHub.

Following the suggestion on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39992606/importing-google-api-fonts-not-applying-in-github-pages) I've changed the `@import` line in the `style.css` file to the following:

```
@import url("//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400italic,600,600italic,800,800italic");
```

Which, for the user in the aforementioned post, seemed to have solved the problem but for my page the wrong font is still used. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: send the github link and we will indagate for you

Comment: After poking around, I found the problem: Once I changed the `@import` call to a non-HTTPS link, Chrome blocked it, thinking it was "unsafe". After manually enabling the "unsafe" script the regular font showed. Now the question is, is there any way around that? Because regular users probably won't be willing to allow "unsafe" scripts on Chrome.

Comment: Allow `unsafe` scripts? No one will do that. change you import to `@import(https:///)`

Comment: @Hitmands Why do need three slashes after the `https:`? (That's what worked for me: 2 slashes didn't work)

Comment: it was a typo, just two.

Answer (score -2):

HTTPS request or external link could be block from Github

But, you can download fonts from Google Font website (on the right) :

[image: screenshot google font]

After you should be able to upload fonts to Github and easily call your font from your CSS (same folder)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "My Font";
    font-weight: bold;
    src: url('myfont.ttf');
}
```

(or `url(github.com/link/to/myfont.ttf)`)

This link will show you how to properly import custom font in Github Pages :
[Adding custom fonts to GitHub pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35718750/adding-custom-fonts-to-github-pages)

Comment: google fonts is a highly optimized cdn, you don't need to download them at all.

Comment: I've been using Google Fonts on my GitHub site with no problem.