# Github Pages: Linked Google Fonts in header of index.html won't show up.

Tags: github-pages, google-font-api

I'm hosting my website project on Github pages and the external link to Google Font API doesn't seem to work. I tried the solution to remove 'http:' from the absolute path as seen in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39992606/importing-google-api-fonts-not-applying-in-github-pages)

Here's the relevant code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/queries.css">
    <link href="/fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css">
    <title>Porsche Digital</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
```

The only difference here is, that I'm not linking via @import url(...) but via href. Where's the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a slash, try this:

```
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css">
```